# xsl increment counter conditional

Tags: xslt, counter

I am trying to increment a counter when a condition is met, for example if a final_score is over 30, count = 1. so if 3 scores are over 30 the final_score should be 3. To get the scores i need to add previous scores so the final score is the calculation of all the other scores

for example

Example XML

```
<scores>
   <score result="20" />
   <score result="10" />
   <score redult="5" />
</score>
```

Main XSL

```
<xsl:call-template name="scores">
<xsl:with-param name="prev_count" select="0"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

Template for scores

```
<template name="scores">
<param name="counter" select="0">
<xsl:variable name="prev_counter" select="$counter+1" />

   <xsl:for-each select="persons/person[id=@id]">//get all the scores
    <xsl:varable name="total_score" select="sum(scores/score)" />//sum them all up
    <xsl:if test="total_score > 40" > //check the result
         <xsl:value-of select="$counter">
     <xsl:call-template name="scores">
       <xsl:with-param name="counter" select="$counter+1"/>
     </xsl:call-template>

    </xsl:if>

   <xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:template>
```

I just cannot work it out, or is my approach way off?

Comment: Have you shown us the full XML here? Your XSLT contains reference to **person** elements, which are not in your XML. It looks like you are try to count the number **person** elements where the sum of all the descendant **score** elements is greater than 30 (or 40). Is that correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, to count the number of **person** elements, where the total of the **score** elements is greater than 30, just use this expression (assuming you are currently positioned on the parent **persons** element)

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(person[sum(scores/score/@result) > 30])" />
```

Comment: thank you, i didn't need a for loop in the end, your answer helped me figure this out after days of going up the wrong path. Thank you. I ended up doing a conditional within the value-of and removed the for-loop. so it ended up much like you said

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="count(person[sum(scores/score/@result > 30 and id=@id])" />